# NoReverseMatch with keywords arguments mesmo existindo uma rota

Tags: python, django, axios

estou tentando enviar um id na url usando axios com a seguinte linha:

```
const request = axios.put("{% url 'forms:save' card_id=card.card_id %}", this.body_text_value).then(response =>{ console.log(this)})
```

e no meu `urls.py` está assim:

```
path('save/<int:card_id>', views.save, name="save"),
```

mas eu continuo recebendo o erro

```
Reverse for 'save' with keyword arguments '{'card_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['forms/save/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

vou deixar aqui meu component do vue e `view.py` embaixo caso for preciso:

```
Vue.component('input-body', {
        template: '<textarea class="form-control body-input" placeholder="Digite um texto para o seu card :)" type="text" name="card_bodytext" v-model="body_text_value" v-on:blur="save" style="height: 300px" > </textarea>',
        props: ['body'],
        data(){
            return{
                body_text_value: this.body 
            }
        },
        methods: {

            save(){
                axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
                axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
                const request = axios.put("{% url 'forms:save' id=card.id %}", this.body_text_value).then(response =>{ console.log(this)})
            }
        }
    })


    new Vue({
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        el: '.cards',
        });
```

`views.py`

```
def boards(request):
    cards = Card.objects.all()
    card_id = Card.card_id
    title = Card.title
    body_text = Card.body_text
    last_modify = Card.last_modify

    return render(request, template_name='forms/card_model.html', context={
        'card_id': card_id,
        'title': title,
        'body_text': body_text,
        'cards': cards,
        'last_modify': last_modify
        })
```

**EDIT 1**

"Muda as variáveis com nome ID" Agora ele só mudou o argumento que está dando erro.

Comment: Minha sugestão de pronto é renomear a variável `id` pois é palavra reservada do Python. Depois atualize o post

Comment: @PauloMarques Tu diz como contexto, a variável dentro da view, no modelo ou em todas as opções?

Comment: @GabrielO, dentro da view quando você faz `id = Card.id` você deveria usar outro nome de variável, como `card_id` por exemplo, por que `id` no python é um método que retorna a identtidade de um objeto

Comment: Sugiro que faça em **todo** lugar que aparecer `id = alguma_coisa`

Comment: @PauloMarques Cara... troquei e não resolveu.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Pois é, foi o que eu fiz. Mas não resolveu...

Comment: @GabrielO, atualiza o post com o novo código.

Comment: @PauloMarques prontinho

Comment: Tente alterar de `const request = axios.put("{% url 'forms:save' card_id=card.card_id %}", this.body_text_value).then(response =>{ console.log(this)})` para `const request = axios.put("{% url 'forms:save' card.card_id %}", this.body_text_value).then(response =>{ console.log(this)})`